# Can I set a custom face conditionally?

Tags: faces, customization

Apparently the correct way to set the default font is the following:

```
(custom-set-faces
 '(default ((t (:family "Raize" :foundry "raster" :slant normal
                :weight normal :height 120 :width normal)))))
```

But it's not portable, that means I cannot copy and paste on a different `init.el` on another computer if I don't check the existence of the correct font before.

A solution is to use a conditional. I already modified my emacs configuration to be environment sensitive, but I cannot solve this issue, I mean I did not manage how to correctly extract the statement from the `(custom-set-faces ...)` block to use within a `(setq ...)`, for instance. Or, as alternative, I wonder if I can use an `if()` in this case.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Are you expecting to also use the Customize interface (UI)? If so then any top-level use of `custom-set-faces` in your init file (or `custom-file`) will be overwritten by Customize.

If you just want some code to do what you describe then something like this should do it:

```
(if XXXXXXXXX
    (custom-set-faces '(default ((t (:family "Raize" :foundry "raster" :slant normal
                                :weight normal :height 120 :width normal)))))
  (custom-set-faces '(default ((t YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY)))))
```

But don't factor out the `custom-set-faces` and place it at top level in your init file, if you also use the Customize UI.

Comment: Well, using a form like `if () custom-set () then custom-set ()` brings to a huge code duplication, doesn't it?

Comment: You can factor out any parts that are duplicated, if you want. (You don't show the two face definitions...) Just don't put `custom-set-faces` at the top level in your init file, if you also use the Customize UI.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, at the end I preferred this solution:

```
(when (member "Raize" (font-family-list))
  (add-to-list 'initial-frame-alist '(font . "Raize"))
  (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "Raize")))
```

in a secondary file. It's more compatible with my legacy configuration.